# Upgarding react-scripts from v4 to v5 gives strange error Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-scripts, cra, custom-react-scripts

I am using CRA and when upgrading react-scripts from v4.0.3 to v5.0.1 I get this strange error

```
Module build failed (from ../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: SOME_FILE_IN_THE_PROJECT.tsx: helperSkipTransparentExpressionWrappers.skipTransparentExprWrapperNodes is not a function
    at transform (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/lib/index.js:147:59)
    at PluginPass.OptionalCallExpression|OptionalMemberExpression (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/lib/index.js:239:9)
    at newFn (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:177:21)
    at NodePath._call (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:53:20)
    at NodePath.call (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:40:17)
    at NodePath.visit (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:100:31)
    at TraversalContext.visitQueue (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:103:16)
    at TraversalContext.visitSingle (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:77:19)
    at TraversalContext.visit (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:131:19)
    at traverseNode (PATHTO_NODE_MODULES/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/traverse-node.js:24:17)
```